# what is the way to remove the REFERRER header that sent by IIS?

Tags: iis-6, http-headers

I have an IIS-6 and i want to find a way that the server do not send  `REFERRER` header response.
How can i do it ?

10x

Comment: Servers don't send a Referer: (sic) header.

Comment: adaptr is correct, "Referer:" is a request header, i.e. sent by the browser.

Comment: i do a redirect call from the iis server, did i can control the referer?

Comment: @haimevgi There isn't one to control in the response.  Do you mean that you don't want the client to send that header to the new location's server when you redirect them?  If that's the case then the answer is no - you can't tell the client to stop following the HTTP spec simply because you don't want the new site to see where the client was redirected from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X-Forwarded-For is inserted by an HTTP proxy, not by your IIS server. If you're getting it directly from your IIS server, then it thinks it's acting as a proxy... which is less likely. More likely is that you have a proxy somewhere that either you don't know about or that you forgot about.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: sorry my fault i mean referrer, i change my question

Comment: The `Referer` header is sent by your browser, not by your server.